# What does own coverage mean in dotCover?

Tags: c#, resharper, dotcover

As the title says in some classes there's an *own coverage* line included as example:

[image: dotCover - own coverage]

What does this mean?

Answer (score 2):

own coverage doesn't include code of generated classes/methods(==lambdas)

Comment: hmm, so the test coverage explorer breaks up a method into sub methods and simple statements. simple statements falls into own coverage part and lamgdas  (I imagine also local functions) has their own coverage results.